# using Windows send-to for creating a one step send to>zip>to email

Tags: email, batch-file, 7zip

In another post on Stack Overflow a user named James L. presented a useful script for adding 7-Zip to the Send to Options in Windows.  I was wondering how hard it would be to take that same principle one more step by sending the results on to be  attached to an email?
Most of the zips I create are done in order to email them and this would cut that down to one click.  The only obstacle being that it could not create a self-extracting ".exe" file to be attached.

Comment: Link to the other post? I have no idea what you're talking about, but it sounds interesting.

Comment: Zipping a file and sending it as an email is pretty easy in Powershell. There are -many- examples available.

Comment: Link to the script posted by James L.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16795607/7zip-sfx-batch-for-sendto-folder/16804798#16804798

Answer (score 0):

Here are three scripts you can stich together.

CreateBlankZip.vbs *Zipname* passed as a parameter, use quotes if spaces in name.

```
Set Ag=Wscript.Arguments
Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set ts = fso.OpenTextFile(Ag(0), 8, vbtrue)
BlankZip = "PK" & Chr(5) & Chr(6)
For x = 0 to 17
    BlankZip = BlankZip & Chr(0)
Next
ts.Write BlankZip
```

Add folder to zip. *DestinationZip SourceFolder*

```
Set objShell = CreateObject("Shell.Application")
Set Ag=Wscript.Arguments
set WshShell = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")

Set SrcFldr=objShell.NameSpace(Ag(1))
Set DestFldr=objShell.NameSpace(Ag(0))
Set FldrItems=SrcFldr.Items
DestFldr.CopyHere FldrItems, &H214
Msgbox "Finished"
```

Send mail and attach file.

```
Set emailObj      = CreateObject("CDO.Message")
emailObj.From     = "dc@gmail.com"

emailObj.To       = "dc@gmail.com"

emailObj.Subject  = "Test CDO"
emailObj.TextBody = "Test CDO"

emailObj.AddAttachment "c:\windows\win.ini"

Set emailConfig = emailObj.Configuration

emailConfig.Fields("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/smtpserver") = "smtp.gmail.com"
emailConfig.Fields("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/smtpserverport") = 465
emailConfig.Fields("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/sendusing")    = 2  
emailConfig.Fields("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/smtpauthenticate") = 1  
emailConfig.Fields("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/smtpusessl")      = true 
emailConfig.Fields("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/sendusername")    = "MyName"
emailConfig.Fields("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/sendpassword")    = "Ppassword1"
emailConfig.Fields.Update

emailObj.Send

If err.number = 0 then Msgbox "Done"
```

Comment: I would prefer something similar to using the options already in SendTo. Such as Sendto compressed Zip + SendTo email recipient.  If I could string those together after creating the zip it would be attached to an email in Outlook ready to be addressed and sent.   The OS is Win10-X64 + Outlook 2016.  I have not been able to get your scripts to work yet but still trying.