# How to move files older than 30 days to archive location and archive the files in archive location?

Tags: windows, batch-file, winrar

I have to write a Windows batch script for the following scenario:

I have log files present in folder `D:\Test` in .txt format. And I have another folder named `D:\Test\archive`.

I have to move the files older than 30 days to archive folder `D:\Test\archive` and then I have to archive all the files present in `D:\Test\archiv` to a single zip file using *WinRAR*.

My zip file should be in the format `ARCHIVE_SYSDATE`.

Answer (score 1):

There is no need to move the files older than 30 days to a subfolder for archiving them. *WinRAR* has built-in options to move files older than x days/hours/minutes directly into an archive file.

Start *WinRAR*, click in menu **Help** on **Help Topics** and select tab **Contents**. There is the list item **Command line mode** with main page *Command line syntax* and with the subitems **Commands** and **Switches** each containing a link to an alphabetic list of all commands and all switches.

From *Alphabetic commands list* the most useful command for your task is:

> **m** move files and folders to an archive

From *Alphabetic switches list* the most useful switches for your task are:

> **-ag[format]** generate archive name using the current date and time
>   **-cfg-**             ignore default profile and environment variable
>   **-ep1**             exclude base folder from names
>   **-ibck**            run WinRAR in background
>   **-m<n>**          set compression method
>   **-r-**                 disable recursion
>   **-to<time>**    process files older than the specified time
>   **-y**                  assume Yes on all queries

Putting all the information from help of *WinRAR* together the command to use is:

```
"%ProgramFiles%\WinRAR\WinRAR.exe" m -agYYYY-MM-DD -cfg- -ep1 -ibck -m5 -r- -to30d -y D:\Test\archive\ARCHIVE_.zip D:\Test\*
```

Note: Switch `-y` disables also output of all error messages.

Answer (score 0):

This should get you started.

```
 forfiles /d -30 /c "cmd /c if not @isdir==TRUE echo @file @fdate"
```

WinRAR isn't part of Windows. Read it's help.

Substitute the command you want (`copy`) for `echo`.

See `forfiles /?` and `copy /?`. Also `XCopy` can probably do it in one line if you specify a date rather than number of days.

See my previous answer to zip using Windows Shell Objects. [using Windows send-to for creating a one step send to>zip>to email](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35108798/using-windows-send-to-for-creating-a-one-step-send-tozipto-email)